# Javascript password validation wont work

Tags: javascript, html, validation, passwords

So im trying to finish off my registration site and require two passwords like any other site. My verification wont work though. Ideally what I want is to have an alert when you change the second password saying they aren't the same or to continue if they are. I thought this function would have worked when i enter onchange="checkpass()" on the password2 input but nothing happens.

```
    function checkpass(pass1,pass2)
{
    pass1=document.txtpassword.value
    pass2=document.txtpassword2.value

    if (pass1 != pass2)
    {
    alert ("Passwords must match")
    }
}
<form action="Home.html" method="post" name="form1" onsubmit="Display()">
  <table bgcolor="white" width="700" border="0" align="center">
  <col width="200">
  <col width="200">


    <tr>
    <th colspan = "2" align = "center" bgcolor="grey"> Fill the form to sign up. </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Forename</td>
      <td>Surname</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
         <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" class="info" required>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtsurname" id="txtsurname" class="info" required />
      </label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Create Username</td>
    <td> Birthday</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>
    <input type="text" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" class="info" required/>
    </label></td>




    <td><select name="DOBMonth" required>
<option value="">    Month  </option>
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
<option value="March">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="August">August</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBDay" required>
    <option value="">   Day  </option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<select name="DOBYear" required>
    <option value=""> Year </option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1998</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
</select>




    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>Confirm Email</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail" id="txtemail" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail(txtemail)" required />
      <td><label>
        <input type="text" name="txtemail2" id="txtemail2" class="info" onchange="ValidateEmail2(txtemail2)" required/>
      </label></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td>Confirm Pasword</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" class="info" required/>
      <td><label>
        <input type="password" name="txtpassword2" id="txtpassword2" class="info" required/ onchange="checkpass(txtpassword,txtpassword2)">
      </label></td>
    </tr>


    <td colspan="2" style="font-size:12px">**Passwords must be at least 8 characters in length.</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


      <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="terms" id="terms" required/>
          I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
        </td></tr>
        <br><br><br>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="notify" value="notify" id="notify" />
          I want to receive notifications by text/email about new products in stock.</label>
          </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
    <td><label>
      <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login"/>
    </label></td>
    <td><label>
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Reset" />
    </label></td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: You are missing 3 of these `;`

Comment: i dont know where from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `checkPass` function, these objects are both undefined:

```
document.txtpassword
document.txtpassword2
```

When your function is run, the undefined objects will cause an error, which will be reported in the console. However, from the perspective of the UI, it will appear like nothing happened. Try this instead:

```
pass1=document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
pass2=document.getElementById("txtpassword2").value;
```

For more information on `getElementById`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById